# ms teams toolkit. white screen on react build if i'm using useGraphWithCredential

Tags: react-hooks, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I am writing an application on the teams toolkit. During development, everything is displayed normally, but when I check build, there is a white screen. I thought there was a problem with routing or in the package.json homepage. But it turned out that the problem is in useGraphWithCredential. When I comment on a piece of code with it, in the build everything is displayed correctly (at least not just a white screen)

I use local hosting using the command `serve -s build` in the project folder

```
import { useGraphWithCredential } from "@microsoft/teamsfx-react";
import { Providers, ProviderState } from "@microsoft/mgt-element";
import { TeamsFxProvider } from "@microsoft/mgt-teamsfx-provider";
import { TeamsFxContext } from "./Context";

import { useContext} from "react";


import {
    tokens,
    makeStyles,
    shorthands,
    Spinner
  } from "@fluentui/react-components";
  


  import {
    Tree,
    TreeItem,
    TreeItemLayout,
    
  } from "@fluentui/react-components/unstable";
  

  const useMenuListContainerStyles = makeStyles({
    container: {
      width: "fit-content",
      height: "100vw",
      minWidth: "250px",
      ...shorthands.padding('20px', '0',  '0', '0'),
    },
    treeItem:{
      backgroundColor: tokens.colorNeutralBackground1,
      borderRadius: tokens.borderRadiusMedium
    }
  });

export default function Assigments({assignments, setAssignments}) {
  const { teamsUserCredential } = useContext(TeamsFxContext);
  const styles = useMenuListContainerStyles();

  const provider = new TeamsFxProvider(teamsUserCredential, scope);
  Providers.globalProvider = provider;
  Providers.globalProvider.setState(ProviderState.SignedIn);

  
  // everything works when I comment on the code below
  const { loading, error, data, reload } = useGraphWithCredential(
    async (graph, teamsUserCredential, scope) => {


      const classes = await graph.api("/education/me/classes").version('beta').get();
      const assignments = await graph.api("/education/me/assignments").version('beta').get();

      return { classes, assignments};
    },
    { scope: [
    "AccessReview.ReadWrite.All", 
    "User.Read.All",
    "EduRoster.ReadBasic", 
    "EduAssignments.ReadWriteBasic", 
    "EduAssignments.Read",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All", 
    "Group.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "GroupMember.Read.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All"

  ], credential: teamsUserCredential }
  );

  // I use these variables to avoid errors when commenting on the code above
  // const data = [];
  // const loading = true;

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>

        <Tree aria-label="Tree">
          {loading ? 
          <Spinner />
          : 
          data && data.classes.value.map( cl =>
            <TreeItem key={cl.id}  itemType="branch">
              <TreeItemLayout className={assignments.classId == cl.id ? styles.treeItem : ""}>{cl.displayName}</TreeItemLayout>
              <Tree>
                {data.assignments.value.map (ass => {
                  if(cl.id == ass.classId && ass.displayName)  
                    return(
                      <TreeItem key={ass.id} itemType="leaf" 
                      onClick={()=>setAssignments({classId: cl.id, assId: ass.id})}
                      
                      >
                        <TreeItemLayout className={assignments.assId == ass.id ? styles.treeItem : ""}>{ass.displayName}</TreeItemLayout>
                      </TreeItem>
                    )
                  }
                  )}
              </Tree>
            </TreeItem>
          )}
      </Tree>
      
      

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to run the application in development mode to see if any error messages or warnings are displayed in the console? Use the command npm start or yarn start to start the development server, and then check the console for any relevant error messages related to the useGraphWithCredential hook.

Comment: Everything works fine in development mode

Comment: You can use the Teams Toolkit to provision cloud resources and deploy your app to the cloud. This will allow you to test your app in a production-like environment and ensure everything works as expected.